# Why do we implement View.OnClickListener if we can have to set android:onClick either way?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-button

**Edit:** No, this is not a duplicate for the given link is asking for the comparison of `setOnClickListener` and `android:onClick`. I'm **not even asking for a comparison**, but I'm asking about the advantage of having an implementation of `View.OnClickListener`.

**Please be free to vote to re-open.**

---

Many people, by preference, use

```
public class TrumpLocator extends Clinton implements View.onClickListener{
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v){
      //...
   }
}
```

However, if I'm not mistaken, either way, on your `Button` you have to do:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

But, again if I'm not mistaken, **if we don't override `onClick` and implement `View.onClickListener`**, we will achieve the same effect:

```
//no override and no "implements onClickListener"
public void onClick(View v){
  //...
}
```

and

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

So, is there any advantage of implementing the method over simply applying the click listener? Isn't it just a waste of code?

Comment: It's a matter of opinion. The Java code makes it more clear, IMO

Comment: @cricket_007 I am completely aware of that, but I'm making sure there aren't any advantages, since implementing seems very useless

Comment: How are your Fragments handling the android:onClick ?

Comment: @OgnianGloushkov by `setOnClickListener`. If we override onClick, then we can use the `android:onClick` with Fragments?

Comment: @PavneetSingh no, it isn't a duplicate. That's the difference between android:onClick and setOnClickLister. Mine is what does implementing onCLickListener achieve.

Comment: please study the answer in the linked question , it will provide the necessary details that you are seeking

Comment: @PavneetSingh I don't see anything, in a direct way, that says anything about `implements OnClickListener` and it's advantage over `onClick:` without the implementation. (Other than the fact that setOnClickListener itself overrides the method.)

Comment: sometimes things can be subtle but in this scenario if you know what both things does then you can easily figure out the advantages but keep in mind the advantages and disadvantages are based on different-2 scenarios so if i want dynamism , if would go with `onclicklistener` otherwise `onclick` plus i can't mark a question as dupe myself, SO is community driven site, :) plus the linked question has necessary details to which can be considered as advantages of one over other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> either way, on your Button you have to do:
>
> ```
> android:onClick="onClick"
> ```

No, this isn't required.

I think you have it backwards maybe. By having `android:onClick="onClick"`, you **need** a `public void` method with that name in the quotes.

```
public void onClick(View v){
  //...
}
```

This is similar to implementing the interface, but not the exact same. In other words, it could just as well be `android:onClick="handleClick"`, then you need

```
public void handleClick(View v){
  //...
}
```

People may not prefer this because it can lead to typos and uncertainty where a click listener is attached.

---

Now, the Activity does not need to implement the interface itself, you can attach anonymous class listeners to the views individually.

Comment: So basically, if you implement it, you DON'T need a public method?

Comment: If you implement an interface, you do have to implement it's methods. Otherwise the code does not compile. I'm saying the XML isn't required

Comment: So, when you're implementing `OnClickListener` you don't need to set the android:onClick in the XML? Never knew that. I must've been doing something wrong in this 2 years of Android programming...

Comment: Please check my edit and reconsider the close vote as I'm not even asking for a comparison but an advantage of using this implementation.

Comment: Go ahead and try it. The XML is completely optional. I'm not sure what takes precedence.

Comment: @AbAppletic as cricket has already supported you very well so you can still accept his answer :) +1 and there is no doubt that it's a good question +1